# Converting Fischer formulas to Newman projections

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

How are line diagrams of molecules converted to their Newman projections? All I got from looking it up is that one may convert a Fischer formula to an eclipsed conformation directly, and that this may further be converted to other conformations.

Doesn't that stop the molecule from having a unique stereochemical configuration?

Comment: The compound is not optically active (it's meso)... So making conformers won't have any change in "configuration"

Comment: Stereochemical configurations are independent of conformational changes since conformational changes just involve bond rotation and not inversion. Caveat: let's assume we're not dealing with atropisomers.

Comment: Oh, the picture's wrong, yeah. I took it down, but my question is general.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment. Stereochemical configurations are unique and not affected by conformations except in very limited cases, which you most likely need not worry about right now.

Comment: Think this as a comment, since I have low points I CANNOT actually comment
step 1: take the bottom carbon (in the line, not the substituent) as the front carbon of the newman
step 2 : in this method of converting line into newmans you will get the groups attached to the mainline in the form of Y (in Newmans) step 3: the left group will go on the left hand of the y and the right side group will go on the right hand of the y

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCOpsnlE02k) gives a good explanation.

Comment: That's for converting *Newman* to *Fischer* projections, which is the opposite.